# DELETE, UPDATE a single record in mysql using playframework

Tags: java, mysql, playframework

Hi I am new to Play framework.I would like to implement CRUD operation using MYSQL database in play framework.

i have able to successfully delete, update the entire table, but not able to successfully delete the single record.  I want to pass the values from html.

```
index.scala.html

@(message: String)

@main("Welcome to Play") {

 <ul id="bars">

    </ul>

<form action="@routes.Application.addBar()" method="post">
    <label for="name"> Enter Your name</label>  <input name="name"/> <br>
    <label for="place"> Enter Your place</label>  <input name="place"/> <br>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>

<form action="@routes.Application.getBars()" method="get">
    <label for="retrieve"> Retrieve the details from table </label>
      <input type="submit"/>
</form>

<form action="@routes.Application.deleteBars()" method="get">
    <label for="Delete"> Delete all the details from table </label>
      <input type="submit"/>
</form>

<form action="@routes.Application.updateBar()" method="post">
    <label for="name"> Enter Your name</label>  <input  name="name"/> <br>
    <label for="place"> Enter Your place</label>  <input name="place"/> <br>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
}
```

Application.java

```
package controllers;

import com.avaje.ebean.Ebean;
import com.avaje.ebean.SqlUpdate;
import java.util.List;
import models.Bar;
import play.*;
import play.data.Form;
import play.db.ebean.Model;
import play.mvc.*;
import play.twirl.api.Content;
import views.html.*;
import play.libs.Json;
public class Application extends Controller {

    public static Result index() {
        int rowCount1 = Bar.find.findRowCount();

        return ok(index.render("Your new application is ready."));
    }

    public static Result addBar() {
        Bar bar = Form.form(Bar.class).bindFromRequest().get();
        bar.save();
        return redirect(routes.Application.index());
    }

    public static Result Login() { 
        Bar bar = Form.form(Bar.class).bindFromRequest().get();
        bar.save();
        return redirect(routes.Application.index());
    }
    public static Result getBars(){
        List<Bar> bars = new Model.Finder(String.class, Bar.class).all();
        return ok(Json.toJson(bars));
    }

    public static Result deleteBars() {
    SqlUpdate down = Ebean.createSqlUpdate("DELETE FROM bar");
    down.execute(); 
    return redirect(routes.Application.index());
    }

    public static Result updateBar() {

    SqlUpdate down = Ebean.createSqlUpdate("UPDATE bar SET place = 'asa'");
    down.execute(); 
    return ok();
    }    

}
```

route is as below:

```
GET     /                           controllers.Application.index()
POST    /bars2                      controllers.Application.addBar()
GET     /bars                       controllers.Application.getBars()
GET     /bars1                      controllers.Application.deleteBars()
POST     /updateBar/                controllers.Application.updateBar()
GET     /updateBar1/                controllers.Application.Login()

# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

What i would like to do is:

1. Passing the name from HTML for Delete, so that i can delete the record.
2. Passing the name, place from HTML for updating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... you need to point the record to delete using `WHERE` clause as in every common [SQL statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/delete.html)

**route**

```
GET /bar/:name/delete  controllers.Application.deleteBar(name: String)
```

**html**

```
<form action='@routes.Application.deleteBar("foo")'>
    <input type="submit" value="Delete `foo`"/>
</form>
```

**action**

```
public static Result deleteBar(String name) {

    SqlUpdate down = Ebean.createSqlUpdate("DELETE FROM bar WHERE name = :param1 ");
    down.setParameter("param1", name);
    int deletedCount = down.execute();

    return ok("Deleted " + deletedCount + " record(s)");
}
```

The same you need to do with the UPDATE, although in Play it may be better to use [`Form<T>` class](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaForms) for mapping models - it will help you with data validation.

Comment: thank you.   How i can pass foo from text box to @routes.Application.deleteBar(?).                                                                       2. Any example for Form<T> Class

Comment: ad.2 just click it in the answer, I linked a documentation there